# Visual Studio Pie Chart - Generate Percentages

Tags: c#, charts, percentage, visual-studio-express

I am generating pie charts by pulling data from SQL tables. The data is an accumulation of hours for different projects.

The charts are building fine but I would like the pie graph to display the respective percentage of each slice of the pie that is being used when the graphs are generated.

I am creating the charts in the method shown below.

```
// Fill Chart with usable data
for (int i = 0; i <= index - 1; i++)
{

    Chart6.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(project[i], projTime[i]);

}
Chart6.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
```

I was hoping there would be a simple command I could pass in the code behind to create this but scouring the web has provided no usable results. The best I have found is [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239373.aspx) but these are not options in Visual Studio Express 2013.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? If one of the answers has helped you please consider marking it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

Prepare like this:

```
   Series S = Chart6.Series["Series1"];
   S.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
   S.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
   S["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
```

Create DataPoints like this if you know the total:

```
   DataPoint p = new DataPoint(project[i], projTime[i]);
   // check your data type for the calculation!
   p.Label = p.YValues[0] + "h =\n"  +
            (100d * p.YValues[0] / total).ToString("00.00") + "%\n"; // my format
```

[image]

If you don't know the total, first set the points, then calculate the total and finally set the label:

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= index - 1; i++)
   {
      S.Points.AddXY(project[i], projTime[i]);
   }

   // calculate the total:
   double total = S.Points.Sum(dp => dp.YValues[0]);

   // now we can set the percentages
   foreach (DataPoint p in S.Points)
   {
       p.Label = p.YValues[0] + "h =\n"  + 
                 (100d * p.YValues[0] / total).ToString("00.00") + "%\n"; // my format
   } 

   chart1.Titles.Add(S.Points.Count + " projects, total " + 
                     total.ToString("###,##0") + " hours");
   chart1.Titles[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14f);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What is a good resource for finding information like this? MSDN was no helpful at all.

Comment: Good question! Besides SO I often succeed when __drilling__ into MSDN, trying harder and harder. I wish I knew the one place where it all comes together..! (See my update with the correct treatment of the total %!)